# How do lbackup backup remote files with root previllege, and without root ssh login?

Tags: rsync

Well, I currently use lbackup to backup files on my remote server. So I logged in with my account, which is NOT root.

And I got below errors, obviously, my account is NOT www-data.

Any suggestions?

$ ls -l /var/www/cache |grep cache
drwx------ 13 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 28 06:27 cache

```
Sun Jul 28 23:53:17 CST 2013

Hard Links Enabled
Synchronizing...
Creating Links
rsync: opendir "/var/www/bbs/cache" failed: Permission denied (13)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync: opendir "/var/www/bbs/files" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/var/www/bbs/store" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/var/www/bbs/config.php": Permission denied (13)

Number of files: 10048
Number of files transferred: 1919
Total file size: 202516431 bytes
Total transferred file size: 16200288 bytes
Literal data: 16200288 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 242097
File list generation time: 0.002 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 39231
Total bytes received: 5617302

sent 39231 bytes  received 5617302 bytes  50731.24 bytes/sec
total size is 202516431  speedup is 35.80
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at      main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]

WARNING! : Data Transfer Interrupted

WARNING! : No mail configuration partner specified.
           To specify a mail partner configuration file add the
           following line into your backup configuration file :

           mailconfigpartner=nameofyourmailpartner.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two possibilities:

a) ignore the files you cannot read (`--exclude=PATTERN`)

b) get read persmissions for these files, either by logging in as another user or by `chmod`-ing the files, whatever is appropriate

Comment: I have got rid of this error with chmod command. But I think this is NOT the ultimate solution. You know.